# Null Pointer Exception on Scale Fitness Test

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Creating a scaleFitnessTest algorithm that tests the fitness of a binarry value and uses weights (prime numbers) and moving them between the 'left' side and 'right' side of a scale

the logic of the actual scale fitness works but when testing the null parameters i get a nullpointer exception

the requirements im trying to meet are that:

> The method should return -100 under the following conditions:
>
> 1)      If either ‘rep’ or ‘weights’ is of size zero or if either is
>   null.
>
> 2)      If the size of ‘rep’ is bigger than the number of weights.

my code is as follow

```
public static double ScalesFitness(ArrayList<Boolean> rep, ArrayList<Double> weights)   {
        if( (rep.size() == 0 || weights.size() == 0) || (rep == null || weights == null) ) {
            return (-100);
        }
        if (rep.size() > weights.size()) {
            return(-100);
        }
        double lhs = 0.0,rhs = 0.0;
        int n = rep.size();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if (rep.get(i) == true) {
                lhs = lhs + weights.get(i);

            }else {
                rhs = rhs + weights.get(i);

            }
        }


        return(Math.abs(lhs-rhs));
    }
```

Comment: You're checking for `null` on `rep` and `weights` after trying to call `size()` on them. Do the null check first.

Comment: Try inversing the conditions in ```( (rep.size() == 0 || weights.size() == 0) || (rep == null || weights == null) )``` to ```( (rep == null || weights == null) || (rep.size() == 0 || weights.size() == 0) )```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by @jsheeran and @D.Lawrence to check for null before calling `size()` on them